# Move Image upwards inside A Div

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing a CSS challenge. I have an image within a box and I need to move it up.

It looks like this currently:
[image]

The picture in the challenge looks like this:
[image]

I would like the green part to be moved up and have that cropped look that you can see in the image above.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="section-1">
    <div class="section-1-flex">
        <div class="description">
            <div class="description-container">
                <h1>Next generation digital banking</h1>
                <p>Take your financial life online. Your Easybank account will be a one-stop-shop for spending, saving, budgeting, investing, and much more</p>
                <button>Request Invite</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <div class="images-container">
                <img src="static/images/bg-intro-desktop.svg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.images{
flex: 1;
}

.images-container{
    height: 700px;
    width: 1000px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to put the images in as background and use background-position to position them.

Comment: you can use `position: absolute`

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks, that looks like it did the trick!

Comment: @CaptainW close it if you found a solution and not post it/mark some solution as correct.

Comment: @francisco I can't, because the answer A Haworth posted isn't one but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it; `background` in CSS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

```
.image-div{
    background: url('./img.webp');
    background-size:120%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Or as the comment says, `position` in CSS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```
.image{
   position:relative;
   top:-20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@AHaworth response did the trick.

Instead of having an image inside the container, you can make the image as the background to move it around the x or y axis.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="section-1">
<div class="section-1-flex">
    <div class="description">
        <div class="description-container">
            <h1>Next generation digital banking</h1>
            <p>Take your financial life online. Your Easybank account will be a one-stop-shop for spending, saving, budgeting, investing, and much more</p>
            <button>Request Invite</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <div class="images-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images{
flex: 1;
}

.images-container{
    height: 700px;
    width: 1000px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("../images/bg-intro-desktop.svg");
    background-position-y: -200px;
}
```